# Add a placeholder to InputNumber in blazor

Tags: c#, html, blazor

I have a simple question, I would like to add a placeholder to InputNumber component.
 I tried this code but It didn't work.

```
//Code behind
public int? Hour { get; set; }
//razor page
<EditForm Model="FilteredEmployees">
  <InputNumber @bind-Value="Hour" min="0" class="form-control" max="10" placeholder="Hour"/> 
</EditForm>
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could be several reasons depending on how you have your code setup. Please try to add more code for a repeatable example, or show the specific error you are getting.

If this input box is displaying 0 instead of "Hour", it's most likely because you are using and int backing field instead of an int? backing field. I just double checked it and having a backing property of

```
public int? Hour { get; set; }
```

shows the placeholder text correctly when the textbox content is null.

If you are getting errors (eg null reference errors), it's most likely you are forgetting the EditForm. Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0

As a minimum example:
This works as expected for me, with or without the validation elements

```
@page "/"

<EditForm Model="@this">
    @*<DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />*@
    <InputNumber @bind-Value="Hour" min="0" class="form-control" max="10" placeholder="Hour" />    
</EditForm>

@code {
    public int? Hour { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot, I did  what you said `int? backing field` and  that works when I have an error, it shows the value of placeholder, but I would like to show a place holder instead of `0`.

Comment: If i've understood your above comment correctly, to get your expected behaviour you would most likely need to add a backing field, expand the property setter to set it to null when it's set to 0. Otherwise you would be looking at changing the component logic, which I would not recommend. I'd also look at why you would want to move away from the default behaviour, (0 displays as 0, null displays placeholder)